# Difficulty in understanding javascript coding

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, javascript-objects

i'm facing difficulty in understanding what this following code does. could anyone here please help me out in understanding this piece of code?

```js
var PnPResponsiveApp = PnPResponsiveApp || {};

PnPResponsiveApp.responsivizeSettings = function () {
    // return if no longer on Settings page
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('/settings.aspx') < 0) return;

    // find the Settings root element, or wait if not available yet
    var settingsRoot = $(".ms-siteSettings-root");
    if (!settingsRoot.length) {
        setTimeout(PnPResponsiveApp.responsivizeSettings, 100);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it adds `responsivizeSettings` function to `PnPResponsiveApp` which gets created if it hasn't been defined earlier. Which part in particular do you have a question about?

Comment: @lxe this line in particular PnPResponsiveApp.responsivizeSettings

Comment: @suman That defines a method of `PnPResponsiveApp` named `responsivizeSettings`. The `function () { ... }` after the `=` specifies any parameters and statements to execute when it's invoked.

Comment: @suman that assigns a function () { ... } to the `responsivizeSettings` property on the `PnPResponsiveApp` object.

Comment: @suman Or do you mean the line with `setTimeout()`?

Comment: @lxe and @ lonathan lonowski, that's all i needed.thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

```
var PnPResponsiveApp = PnPResponsiveApp || {};
```

The above line ensures that the PnPResponsiveApp variable gets its old value if it already exists, otherwise it's set to a new object.

```
PnPResponsiveApp.responsivizeSettings = function () {
```

Here, a new function is created.

```
    // return if no longer on Settings page
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('/settings.aspx') < 0) return;
```

If the URL of the current page isn't the settings page, then the function exits immediately.

```
    // find the Settings root element, or wait if not available yet
    var settingsRoot = $(".ms-siteSettings-root");
```

This gets all elements with a class of `.ms-siteSettings-root`.

```
    if (!settingsRoot.length) {
        setTimeout(PnPResponsiveApp.responsivizeSettings, 100);
        return;
    }
```

If any elements were found (if the length of the node list is not zero), then call the PnPResponsiveApp.responsivizeSettings function in 100 milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Very easy code basically, I'll explain what's going on:

```
var PnPResponsiveApp = PnPResponsiveApp || {};
```

This is very common way to see if the variable is already defined and if not, avoid throwing error and equal it to an empty object, It's used in many frameworks and library, very safe way to check if the var is there already... look at here for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

```
PnPResponsiveApp.responsivizeSettings = function () {};
```

This is basically a simple function but attached to the object PnPResponsiveApp - if just responsivizeSettings = function () {}; it's attached to window Object

```
 if (window.location.href.indexOf('/settings.aspx') < 0) return;
```

this is Checking if the Link in the linkbar has settings.aspx - indexOf return -1 if it doesn't contain the string, so if it's not settings.aspx it returns -1 that's smaller than 0 and then the whole function return ... the second return basically return undefined

```
 var settingsRoot = $(".ms-siteSettings-root");
```

This is basically look for all element with class of ms-siteSettings-root and equal them to variable settingsRoot, it could be a single DOM or multiple...

```
   if (!settingsRoot.length) {
```

and this basically check if any DOM element has ms-siteSettings-root class, length return a Number, so if it's not there, it returns 0, if there is return 1,2,3 etc... and 0 is equal to False in JavaScript and bigger than 0 is equal to True, so this way we can check if it's there...

```
setTimeout(PnPResponsiveApp.responsivizeSettings, 100);
```

so if the settingsRoot is there, we execute this function block and with setTimeout we wait 100ms... setTimeout always works in this manner, setTimeout(function(), time); and the same return happens at the end...

Hope it's informative enough...